# How to redirect mails from one address to another with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, email, redirect

Is it possible (and how) to redirect mails with htaccess to gmail?

Currently, I have a website and I use phpmailer library to send mails where I set field FROM as: pete@mydomain.com. I set reply address the same way. I have to contact forms set up like this on a virtual server (using apache on win I think - I'm not an expert) - *I understand it's possible to set up reply mail to my gmail directly with phpmailer but I'd like to redirect it from server if possible*.

Now, I'd like to put some code into htaccess inside respective directories so when mail request comes to server it automaticalle redirects it to my gmail email.

Something like this

```
mydomain.com:
Incoming email to pete@mydomain.com -> htaccess -> redirecting to myemail@gmail.com
```

I have no idea if this is possible with htaccess or if even it is possible?

Thank you very much for any kind advice you can provide, I'm lost in this.

Comment: You will want to set the redirect on the mail server so that I can handle it while the email is sent out your smtp server. You will have to provide additional information on what type of mail server you are using. For example if you use postfix you will want to setup an email alias or mail forward.

Comment: I have to say I have no idea. It's a hosting that was set up for me and I'm amateur in this :(.

Comment: I found out there is a console and there is a directory called postfix. I'm not sure if that implies we use it or not but our programmer who was taking care of this got investigated by criminal investigators so excuse me if this was not helpful please.

Comment: htaccess is for configuring Apache, it has nothing to do with sending or redirecting emails.

Comment: @VicoLemp it depends on how the code is setup and if it uses the postfix mail server or not. You will probably have to get some help with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be out of my league so I'll do as you say and find somebody who can do it for us rather than trying to hack my way through and hope for the best xD. I really appreciate everyones reactions it helped to get my thoughts straight.